# Clarification on Relative homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have topological spaces $A$, $B$ $\subset$ X. Further assume $A$, $B$ are homeomorphic. Then shouldn't it directly follow from the definitions that $H_{n}(X,A)$ and $H_{n}(X,B)$ are isomorphic, since the chain complexes ,$C_{n}(X)/C_{n}(A)$ , $C_{n}(X)/C_{n}(B)$ should be isomorphic.

However in this exercise in [Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) P-132 , Exercise 17(b), this doesn't happen. Using the fact that we have a good pair,i can calculate relative homology in this case and they turn out to be different for both the cases. I can't figure out the gap in my reasoning in the first para. Perhaps i haven't considered the boundary maps properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When computing homology, it is not just the chain complexes, but also the boundary maps that are important. Because $A$ and $B$ are included in different ways in the simplicial complex structure of $X$ in the problem you references, the boundary maps will be different, so the homology groups will also be different. There is also a theorem, which you are probably already using: if $(X,A)$ is a good pair, $$H_n(X,A)=\tilde H_n(X/A).$$ Because of the different inclusion of $A$ and $B$ into $X$, the spaces $X/A$ and $X/B$ are not homeomorphic. One is the wedge of two tori, the other is a torus with two pints identified. Since these are different spaces, we don't expect their reduced homology groups to be the same.